# What javascript frameworks should I become familiar with?

Tags: javascript, frameworks

jQuery has served me well, it has given me an excellent introduction to Javascript but now I want to move onto something else. A good developer has a good knowlege of lots of different technologies.

So what frameworks should I move onto? I just want something good to put on my CV. There are so many out there and they all more or less achive the same thing. But because people have their own preferences I want to be as versitile as possible for other peoples sake.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jQuery is incredibly easy to use even for a beginner, very extensible with tons of useful user-created plugins and useful even for advanced scripting. It's made javascript accessible to me, and that's saying something. It's fast and tiny. I believe it's the top dog for a reason.

But Ext also looks promising for business applications:

http://www.extjs.com/

Comment: +1 for ExtJS. It was the first Javascript toolkit I ever used, and I really liked the API. Then I had to do a project using YUI, and was more than a little disappointed.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I like JQuery, too.

You can learn prototype or mootools.

Comment: Now distributed with ASP.NET, it will become de facto standard.

Comment: Why will it be de facto because it ships with asp.net? Jquery is a good framework regardless of asp.net's involvement. If it continues to be developed well it will stand the test of time, not because it's ships with asp.net.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want something good to put on
>   my CV.

Well if that is your goal..., you should probably go by popularity.

In order according to [this study](http://royal.pingdom.com/2008/06/11/javascript-framework-usage-among-top-websites/):

1. Prototype
2. JQuery
3. MooTools
4. YUI
5. Rest is insignificant

Comment: Been meaning to try that Rest is insignificant framework. Any good?

Comment: @Kirschstein: What were the search results? ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would say GWT (Google Web Toolkit): although not strictly Javascript but definitely very useful and productive.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/). There are tons more out there, but really they offer the same basic functionality:

- A method to bind methods because of javascript's silly way of handling `this`.
- Sane way to do AJAX.
- Helper DOM look-up functions like `$` for jQuery.

So I expect that once you know two you can start to use others pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

None. You can't really learn Javascript by only using libraries, so I suggest that you take a stab at learning the language itself.

Comment: I'm wondering, Does it really help to learn javascript ? I started with raw javascript then moved to Jquery and for some reason I feel that I could've just skipped the javascript part.. I'm really interested to know what are your arguments ?

Comment: @Soufiane: Well, if you only are going to use Javascript for what jQuery provides, you don't really need any programming knowledge as you can just copy and paste examples from the web. It's when you want to do something more than just then plain vanilla that you need to be able to build something yourself.

Comment: Yes, if you know JavaScript you will find that you now have better understanding of jQuery as well.jQuery is a nice abstraction and does a good job of speeding up your productivity. But once you need to code something atypical with jQuery, you'll have to come back to plain JavaScript. Therefore, knowledge of plain JavaScript is MUST if you want to be a serious javascript developer.

Answer (score 0):

I think the differences between jQuery and prototype and the most other frameworks are quite small.
If you want to make a lot of GUI stuff you should definitly take a look at [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/). The Api is very clean and easy to learn and you can do a lot with it.
Another interesting framework for GUI stuff is [qooxdoo](http://qooxdoo.org/).